# Syscalls in User-Space

Tags: c, linux, glibc, system-calls

I understand how system calls work internally, i.e. how they are implemented in a kernel and how they are invoked from user space (via creating an exception and having the syscall number in the right register). The thing I still don't know is:

What's the best practice to implement User-Space functions that correspond to syscalls? (Such as all the familiar functions like `open`, `fork`, `dup`, etc.). Hence, I want to call a function in User-Space that is named like the actual syscall, instead of using the `syscall(number)` function.

AFAIK they can easily be created via some Macro provided by the unistd.h header, but I don't really know how to use it. I've read something about `__SYSCALL` and `_syscall`, but if I look into the sources, I don't really find an understandable example to work with. So does anyone know how to make a customized syscall "available" in User-Space?

Comment: "via creating an exception"?!

Comment: I'd suggest taking a close look at the underpinnings of valgrind.

Comment: @KerrekSB I am talking about a process exception, or Software-Interrupt if you may call it like that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Valgrind seems to be a virtual machine that executes programs as native bytecode. I don't think that this is what I need to look at, since I've never used it before.

Comment: @PhilippMurry, ...and it runs custom wrappers for syscalls. Sure, it's big and heavyweight, but it does what you're asking for.

Comment: @PhilippMurry, ...though if you want a lighter-weight way to wrap syscalls, well, there's always ptrace.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I don't really need it, I'm just curious how a syscall wrapper would be implemented natively, i.e. directly in glibc. I think I found a good link that I will post as an answer. But thanks for the help.